# Slick slider wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

проблема такова не могу вывести слик через ACF, суть такова что img не подгружается.

```
        <div class="our_works__inner">
    <?php if( have_rows('slider_content') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('slider_content') ): the_row(); ?>
       <?php
        $slideimage = get_sub_field('slider_image');
        $slidetitle = get_sub_field('slider_title');
        ?>
        <div class="slick-container">
          <img src="<?php echo $slideimage['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slideimage['alt']; ?>" />
          <p class="info-title text-center"><?php echo $slidetitle; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

JS - слайдер

```js
$('.our_works__inner').slick({
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```

Для ACF сделан репитор c image + tittle, для posts, и почему то не подтягивает, буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно проверить что вы выводите на странице, убедитесь, что вы используете данные по назначению. http://prntscr.com/pqvzww - если вы выбрали url, то в вашем коде `<?php echo $slideimage['url']; ?>` лишним будет `['url']`.
2. Я советую использовать id изображения, что бы на деле вывести изображение через функцию [wp_get_attachment_image()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image).

Пример кода:

```
<?php
  $image= get_field('image_blog_post');
  if ($image) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, 'full', false, array(
      'class' => 'post-content__img',
      'loading' => 'lazy'
      ));
  }
?>
```

Что бы на страницу вывело изображение с вариантами размеров под разные девайсы через [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images).